# Alterac Valley Bonus Honor

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've been reading quite [a lot about it](http://www.wowwiki.com/Alterac_Valley), from [different](http://www.worldofwarcraft.com/pvp/battlegrounds/info-alteracvalley.html) [sources](http://www.wowhead.com/zone=2597/alterac-valley#comments), but I still couldn't figure out how, in a *winning call to arms game*, I get to see people gaining up to 7000 points, while most of the team get regular 5000 at most. Sometimes the difference is from 4k to 6k, so always around 2k more than most others.

What are those people doing different? **How do they get that many extra honor points?**

Usually around 5-10 guys get the extra points. I had some obvious points to consider, but could confirm from experience it's not directly related to capturing towers, giving killing blows, dealing damage, healing, even getting regular HK or anything else listed everywhere as giving bonus points - I believe those bonus go to the whole faction.

Anyway, can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're referring to the daily Call to Arms, keep in mind that you gain a larger chunk of bonus honor for the *first time* in a given day that you complete it.

Comment: Does that bonus show up in the honor leaderboard though? I wouldn't think that it would.

Comment: This. Yes, you get the extra bonus when it's the daily or the weekend BG.  Yes, it shows up in the window. The reason you consistently see them even when it's not the daily is that different servers have different daily BGs (otherwise, it wouldn't be as balanced). You can easily test this by noting that you're in the 2k-extra group for your first win, but in the future you're at the bottom like the rest.

Comment: I was going to try just that @glowcoder, and I believe that must be the case... I just haven't accepted this yet, because I still haven't got the time to go and confirm - plus I have to be able to do it in a Call to Arms day, and we have got to win. I actually tried few times, but we have always lost so far.

Comment: Yup. I just confirmed this right now. It becomes pretty obvious once you know it.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumptions about honor are not quite correct. All the objective-based bonus honor is awarded to the entire faction - for destroying towers, defeating the general, etc. And no honor is awarded at all for doing damage or healing (on their own).

But honor awarded for honorable kills is different - it's split evenly among people within a certain range of the kill. (If the people were not all group members it would be split unevenly, but since everyone in the battleground is grouped this doesn't come into play.) This is fairly easy to confirm; if you stand near a heated battle you'll see small honor awards rolling in, and if you stay in the entrance tunnel you won't.

The range seems to be generous - this is why it used to be somewhat fashionable for people to farm honor by staying at the blacksmith in Arathi Basin. Not only would they get a defender's buff that increases honor, but by staying in the center of the map they would be within range of most kills that occur at the other nodes. (The range for receiving HK credit is not long enough to reach from the lumber mill to the gold mine, or the stables to the farm.)

And since HK awards are the only honor in battlegrounds that isn't awarded to everyone (except for the daily bonus), I'd say the answer to your question is probably that the people at the top of the honor list have been actively maximizing their HKs - by staying within range of the heaviest fighting, and by staying alive as much as possible. (For example, defending a bottleneck is a good way to do this.)

Also, it's worth noting that in AV it's quite common for people to come and go during a match, so at the end of any round there will always be a fair honor gap between people who were present at the start of the match and everyone else - even people who join only a minute or two late will often miss the bonus awarded for killing the faction captain.

Comment: I specifically said about HK, but I'll re-enforce here. I've done one after other AV and they consistenly win with same team from beginning - no changes. Eventually I noticed people on the 7k range with no HK and no stats what so ever. Almost zero on all, except of course HK - because they were somehow actively doing something else. My question here is "what else?". I'm pretty sure anyone who pays close attention for long enough either got to the same question or know what I'm talking about.